# variable not expanding when using sed in bash for loop

Tags: bash, loops, sed, expand

I need to run a program (*hole2* for those interested) on a dir full of iteratively named files. I've written a `bash` script to loop over the required files, edit the required config file and run the program.

I've been having trouble with the `sed` commands inside the loop, as they don't seem to be expanding the variables properly.

Code below;

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/hole/dir
shopt -s nullglob
for i in /path/to/files/*.pdb;
do
    echo $i
    sed -i "s=coord  /path/to/files/=coord ${i}=g" config_file.inp
    var=${i:72}
    hole < configfile.inp > hole_out_$var.txt
    sed -i "s=coord ${i}=coord  /path/to/files=g" config_file.inp
done
```

The `$i` does not seem to be expanding; I'm aware there are some similar SO posts on this topic but none of the answers seemed to help in this instance. I've tried enclosing the `sed` command in double or single quotes, tried enclosing the `$i` with double, single or both quotation marks, with and without the braces, but my `$i` variable is being written as *$i* in my config file and not the expanded file path it needs to be.

I hope the above makes sense. I'm not set on using `bash` and am open to alternative ways to achieve this.

Addition of both comments from kasul (which alas I had already tried) and kvantour (set -x to the shebang) results in the following output

code:

```
set -x

cd /home/jonah/hole2
shopt -s nullglob

for i in /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/*.pdb;
do
#      echo $i
    sed -i "s=coord  /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/=coord '"${i}"'=g" hole.inp
    var=${i:72}
    hole < hole.inp > hole_c_$var.txt
    sed -i "s=coord '"${i}"'=coord  /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/=g" hole.inp
done
```

I've left the full file paths in for clarity (/ laze) this time

output

```
sed -i 's=coord '\''/media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10705.pdb'\''=coord  /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/=g' hole.inp
+ for i in /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/*.pdb
+ sed -i 's=coord  /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/=coord '\''/media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10706.pdb'\''=g' hole.inp
+ var=tst10706.pdb
+ hole
+ sed -i 's=coord '\''/media
```

I killed it before it ran through all 20k clusters*, but

The output from the hole program for tst10706 still reads;
Error
Cannot open pdb co-ord input file:
$i

NB: Anyone who'd cleverly like to point out the cluster analysis on 20k structures is dumb, please feel free to, I have since fixed this horrendously flawed methodology, but I would still like to find the code issue for future use.

Thanks

Comment: What output do you get if you replace `echo $i` with `echo "s=coord  /path/to/files/=coord ${i}=g"`? Note this is not a `sed` problem; the shell is responsible for expanding `$i` in the double-quoted string before `sed` ever runs.

Comment: @Jonah : This behaviour can not occur if the script is exactly as you posted it. I suggest that you run it under `-x`. This will show your commands after parameter expansion.

Comment: after the shebang, type `set -x` on the next line and rerun.

Comment: @chepner This changed the output of the script to

s=coord /path/to/files/=coord /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10687.pdb=g

while the original output ($i) was;

s=coord /path/to/files/=coord /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10687.pdb=g

Comment: @kvantour, this changed the stdout i was getting to;

+ echo 's=coord /path/to/files/=coord /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10271.pdb=g'
s=coord /path/to/files/=coord /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10271.pdb=g
+ sed -i 's=coord  /media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/=coord '\''/media/psf/Lickitung/1-PROJECTS/Trigger_Pore/_Analysis/CLUSTERS/c_align/tst10271.pdb'\''=g' hole.inp
+ var=tst10271.pdb
+ hole
etc
but didn't alter the script outcome
What is the -x doing?

Comment: @Jonah the `set -x` prints every line it is executing after all substitutions. This way you can follow your code and see what is going on. Can you paste the output in the original question using [edit]?

Comment: First, I generally disapprove of using the `-i` option to sed for several reasons.   2nd, I have to wonder why you're using it at all, since you seem to be attempting to change the file, then use it, and then change it back!  Just run the filter and pipe the output directly to `hole`.  Using `-i` is a travesty, and you seem to not want it at all, so take it out and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: @WilliamPursell
This a really useful answer.
The config file in question has loads of other stuff in it that needs to remain 
constant, how would I pipe just the bit that i wanted to change with sed to the hole program?

Also, if you have any links as to why I shouldn't be using the -i option, I'm all ears.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `hole < hole.inp > hole_c_$var.txt`, just do `sed "..." | hole > hole_c_"${var}".txt`